# Jnlp error: Could not find main class

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I am also face similar problem:

I have a TrainingDNA.jnlp for TrainingDNA.jar. The jar and jnlp both are host from Tomcat Apache 6(webapps/root) on linux server. The jnlp launches jar file application fine in 64bit Windows OS but when I try from: 
1. IE browser 32bit OS, Win XP it gives me error : "Could not find main class : com.sangha.gui.Main, Program will exit" , I had enabled java console to see output, below is the java console error:

```
Java Web Start 1.6.0_43
Using JRE version 1.6.0_43-b01 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\s-projectusertwod
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
java.class.path=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\deploy.jar
java.majorVersion=1
java.minorVersion=6
Class-Start=com.sangha.gui.Main
Class-Memory=1024
-propsResource
/com/sangha/gui/client.cfg
DNA.Client
Java Path=null
MAX MEMORY=259522560
Executing: javaw.exe -Xmx1024M -classpath C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\lib\\deploy.jar com.sangha.gui.Main -propsResource /com/sangha/gui/client.cfg DNA.Client
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sangha/gui/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sangha.gui.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

2.From Firefox just java Java 6 window comes and java console flashes for a second.

PS: There is nothing wrong with the TrainingDNA.jar since it runs fine on 32bit if I don't use JNLP and double click and run it.

Below is my jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://192.168.244.25:8080/" href="TrainingDNA.jnlp">
<information>
<title>Training DNA</title>
<vendor>DNA</vendor>
<homepage href="http://www.google.com" />
<description>Web Porting Testing</description>
</information>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<jar href="TrainingDNA.jar" main="true" />
<j2se version="1.6+" />
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.sangha.util.Relauncher" />
</jnlp>
```

*The main class mentioned above 'Relauncher' is just an entry point to the application, in this class it reads a config file 'relauncher.config' which in turn specifies the main class for application. the contents of config file are as below:

```
Class-Start: com.sangha.gui.Main
Class-Memory: 1024
Class-Arg-0: -propsResource
Class-Arg-1: /com/sangha/gui/client.cfg
Class-Arg-2: DNA.Client
java.majorVersion: 1
java.minorVersion: 6
```

Regards,
Akita

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: No result from JaNeLA, my jnlp works fine with 64bit java, only with 32bit java it gives "Main class not found error"

Comment: Is it 64bit jre6 or 7 or both that work with jws

Comment: it works with 64bit jr6, have not tried with jre7 since application req is jre6 only, don't know why it fails for 32bit jre6

Comment: It started working in 32bit java, did foll:
Replaced: 
 <resources>
  <jar href="TrainingDNA.jar" main="true" />
  <j2se version="1.6+" />
 </resources>                       
with:
 <resources>
  <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Xmx1024M"/>
  <jar href="TrainingDNA.jar" main="true" />
  <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
 </resources>

Answer (score 0):

(@akita's comment reposted as answer, to get some formatting)

It started working in 32bit java, did foll:

Replaced:

```
<resources> 
    <j2se version="1.6+" />
    <jar href="TrainingDNA.jar" main="true" /> 
 </resources>
```

with:

```
<resources> 
    <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Xmx1024M"/>
    <jar href="TrainingDNA.jar" main="true" /> 
    <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/> 
</resources>
```